# When I'm texture painting, how do I know which texture i'm painting onto?

Tags: texturing

Is the UV/Image editor window supposed to automatically change to the active texture or something? Or is there another way blender indicates which one you're working on?

Comment: Is it supposed to?

Comment: Hi i updated the description to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to control which image receives paint strokes, is to select it in the list of available paint slots, which can be found under slots in the toolbar.

[image: texture painting slots]

This works with both Blender Render and Cycles. If a UV/Image editor is visible it will get updated to show the active image.